# How to handle any Unix/DOS/Mac text file in flex scanner

Tags: newline, flex-lexer

I want my flex scanner to handle text files with newlines encoded using any of lf (Unix), cr (Mac), or cr lf (DOS).  I don't care about maintaining an exactly accurate line count.

Doing nothing special in the .l file regarding end of lines and compiling under Ubuntu, my scanner works with both Unix and DOS files.  However, Mac files make it fail.  Adding a rule to throw away any character not matched (i.e. just a line with the character `.`) doesn't help.  I believe that lex is looking for \n to end lines, and ignoring the \r's in the DOS files, but fails on the Mac files because no \n's appear, so it never actually thinks it reads a line.

There must be simple way to handle this!  Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

(F)lex does exactly what you ask it to do. If you need to recognise line endings and you want to accept all three forms, you'll need to tell it to do that, using a pattern like `(\r\n?|\n)`.

(F)lex is not intrinsically line-oriented, except for three features. These features assume lines end with a `\n`, which is true for both DOS and Unix text files. If you want to handle old-style Mac files, you'll need to implement those features yourself.

1. Start-of-line patterns (patterns starting with a `^`). You can use start conditions (see below).
2. End-of-line patterns (patterns ending with a `$`). The `$` can simply be replaced with a trailing context operator:

   ```
   (some_pattern)$
   ```

   ⇒ `(some_pattern)/(\r\n?|\n)`
3. Automatic line counting using `%option yylineno`. (Flex only) You won't be able to count automatically; you need to do it manually:

   ```
   (\r\n?|\n)    { ++yylineno; }
   ```

   Of course, that action needs to be added to every rule which matches a newline, and if some rule might match several newlines, you'd need to rescan the match to count the newlines. That's a pain, but it's usually possible to replace a long pattern like that with a series of matches in a start condition.

(F)lex allows you to make a set of rules conditional on the state of the lexer, encapsulated in a [start condition](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html#Start-Conditions). For example, if you needed to do something different for a pattern right at the beginning of a line, you could make a transition to a start-of-line start condition in your pattern for newline:

```
%x LINE_START
%%
 /* ... */
\r\n?|\n    { ++yylineno; BEGIN(LINE_START); }
/* ... */
pattern                { /* pattern is not at the start of a line */ }
<LINE_START>pattern    { /* pattern is at the start of a line */
                         BEGIN(INITIAL);
                       }
<*>other-pattern       { /* might or might not be at the start of a line */
                         BEGIN(INITIAL); /* In case it wasn't */
                       }
```

If you are encountering some other kind of problem, you should prepare a proper question with a detailed problem description and a [mcse] which exhibits the problem.

Comment: Thanks!  Your suggestion to explicitly recognize all line endings solved my problem, which was caused by a pattern that used $, which only matches \n.

Comment: @HAK: oh, right. I forgot about $. I'll add that to the answer.